# How do I simplify $\delta_{ij} \delta^{jk}$?

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products, tensors, kronecker-delta, kronecker-symbol

How do I simplify $\delta_{ij} \delta^{jk}$?

I know that $\delta_{ij} \delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$, but what do I do if the there's a Kronecker Delta symbol with upper indices and one with lower indices?

Comment: How about $\delta_i^k$?

Comment: That was my guess, but I'm not sure if it's correct. I don't know how to show that's true.

Comment: The question is notation, not math.